# How to get distinct of all sub-sub-property via Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I am trying to display all possible values for a sub-property. Below I am trying to get all possible colors for all products into a single variable. How can I get allDistinctColors below?

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = GetAllProducts();
IEnumerable allDistinctColors = ???

public class Product
{
  public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to select multiple output items (options) per input item (product) and concatenate them into a single enumeration for further querying:

```
var allDistinctColors = products
    .SelectMany(p => p.Options)
    .Select(o => o.Color)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var allDistinctColors = products
     .SelectMany(p => p.Options.Select(o => o.Color))
     .Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

The query syntax also works nicely for this:

```
var allDistinctColors = (from p in products
                         from o in p.Options
                         select o.Color).Distinct();
```